# Need autoclick functionality in JSF form

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I need to automatically click the Login link after the JSF page below is loaded. Please help!
this form will display a login link and open a new a new window once the login link is clicked .
it would also be okay if i can directly submit the form without showing Login link.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
        xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
        xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
        <head>
                <title>MY System &#174;</title>
                <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
                <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
                <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
                <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="My System" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
                        href="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/style/source.css"></link>
                <script type="text/javascript"
                        src="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/js/Utility.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <ui:include src="common/header.xhtml" />
                <div class="table"
                        style="position: absolute; top: 160px; width: 960px; text-align: center; float: center; margin-left: auto;">
                        <form id="initForm">
                                <span class="warning"> Welcome to MY System, please <a
                                        href=""
                                        onclick="newSourceWindow('${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/home.jsf');"
                                        style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">Login</a>
                                        to start. </span>
                        </form>
                        <rich:spacer height="40" />
                        <ui:include src="common/footer.xhtml" />
                </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give Id to your `span`.
Access it through Javascript and you can do anything with it, in your case trigger click.

```
<span id="welcomeLink">
...
</span>
```

Since your `span` is in normal `form` no need to use form id while assessing.
If your `span` is in `h:form` then you have to attach the form id like this `formId:spanId`.

so the Javascript code would be:

```
var spanEle = document.getElementById('welcomeLink');
spanEle.click()
```